# GIT: I want to merge branch B into branch A but I don't want to merge all of the changes. I want some of the differences on A to be copied onto B

Tags: git, merge

I am merging branch B onto branch A. There is a lot of cruft. If there is some debug code on B/file1 I want to "unstage" that hunk so now that piece of code is equal on B and A. However, I don't think you can unstage with merges. I am doing it by hand but this is very time consuming and prone to error. Basically, I want to merge two branches, and pick what changes go into the merge. I can't use cherry pick because there are too many commits.

Answer (score 1):

If you really mind against cherry-pick (probably, I would stay with it, using its sequencer capability), the could be a way like this:

```
git merge --log --no-commit BranchB
git revert --no-commit BadCommit1 BadCommit2...
git commit
```

The idea is to create a merge, and then to revert 'bad changes' in it. Technically it does exactly what you need. But depending on details of your case this could be a good thing or not, since *people's expectations* from a merge usually assume that all the features from BranchB are already in BranchA. So, use with care.

Answer (score 1):

The golden command for me has been Interactive Rebasing via `git rebase -i HEAD~<number>`. I find it very easy to re-write your git history in this way. Here's how for your specific case:

1. Make a temporary branch just incase you make any mistakes:

   ```
   git checkout -b <temp-branch-name>
   ```
2. Delete off the commits you don't want:

   ```
   git rebase -i HEAD~<number-of-commits-backwards-you-want-to-go>
   pick <commit-that-i-want>
   pick <another-commit-that-i-want>
   ```
3. Save, then switch to your destination branch and merge the temporary branch into it:

   ```
   git checkout <destination-branch>
   git merge <temp-branch-name>
   ```

Comment: Let's say I branched off master a while ago, and have been regularly merging master into my branch.  If I just pick the more recent commit from the branch, and merge it onto master, will I have everything, or only the changes that were introduced in that last commit?

Comment: On your first statement I would highly recommend that while you're on your development branch, you simply do `git rebase master` when you want to update it, because it will tuck all the updates from master underneath your new commits. Regarding your second statement, "<number-of-commits-backwards-you-want-to-go>" means that everything further back than that distance will be included, plus the commits you pick to have on top of those.